# Add a tag like a post

Tags: taxonomy, tags, post-type

For days I'm looking at different threads Stackexchange, but I can not find the solution. I hope you can help me out.

I created a post_type called "bands". I'm trying to, from another post_type (eg entries or pages), there is a meta_box as tags that adding a term, we add the post_type called "bands".

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no native functionality in WordPress to relate posts to each other (only group posts with taxonomies).

You will either have to develop custom solution, or try to make use of existing plugins. [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) is considered staple for post relationships.